# Openfire Custom DB inegration fails after upgrade

Tags: integration, upgrade, openfire

I was using custom Authentication, users and groups integration on Openfire 3.7.1. After upgrade to 3.8.0, the custom integrations are not working. Because one of the users from custom DB was the Admin, I cannot login to admin console too.
The ofProperty table in the database is as it was before upgrade, with the 3 providers set to

1. org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider
2. org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider
3. org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.JDBCGroupProvider

The integration SQLs are intact too.

Anyone here hit a similar issue after upgrade ?
Please help.

Regards
Sree

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Ran the sql dump for ofProperty table, restarted openfire.
Seems some properties were changed by new installation.

Regards
Sree